# What issue I am facing for creating simple mysql Stored Procedure using phpmyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I can't create stored procedure using phpmyAdmin and I don't think the issue is syntax..
maybe the issue is delimiter? here is part of my code:

```
BEGIN
    SET
        @statement = CONCAT(
            'SELECT
    `usr`.`FIRST_NAME` AS firstName, 
    `usr`.`LAST_NAME` AS lastName,
    `usr`.`EMAIL` AS email, 
    `usr`.`MOBILE_NUM` AS mobileNum,
    `sch`.`SUNDAY` as sunday,
    `sch`.`MONDAY` as monday,

FROM
    (
                `Appian`.`LDA_USER_DETAILS` `usr`
            RIGHT JOIN `Appian`.`LDA_DRIVER_DETAILS` `sch`
            ON `usr`.`USER_DETAILS_ID` = `sch`.`USER_DETAILS_ID` 
            AND 
           `sch`.`DRIVER_DETAILS_ID` IS NOT NULL

 )
    Where 1=1',
            `searchText`,
            `groupByText`,
            `orderByText`
        );
    PREPARE
        stmt
    FROM
        @statement;
    EXECUTE
        stmt;
    DEALLOCATE
PREPARE
    stmt;
END
```

I try to claim this code in phpmyAdmin:

[image]

But it never works, is that probably the issue of Delimiter? if so, how should I set up the delimiters?
Here is the error message I got:

[image]
I am not very familiar with phpmyAdmin, please guide me, thanks!

Comment: Ignoring delimiters for now the lines      `searchText`,   `groupByText`,   `orderByText` are not within the closing quote for the @statement and throw unknown column errors - also they don't make a lot of sense since there is no comparison happening.

Comment: @P.Salmon  Thank! the issues I found out is because the ` ` is wrong.